# Why does SimpleDateFormatter returns an error

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

This method is called and should give the Time out to the void msgOut(String s)

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String uhrzeit = sdf.format(new Date());

        msgOut("[System] Zeit: "+uhrzeit);

        txtSName.setText("");
        txtSName.requestFocus();
    }
```

But every time it returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(ZoneInfo.java:236)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2340)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2312)
    at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1804)
    at java.util.Calendar$Builder.build(Calendar.java:1508)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarProviderImpl.getInstance(CalendarProviderImpl.java:88)
    at java.util.Calendar.createCalendar(Calendar.java:1666)
    at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1655)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(SimpleDateFormat.java:657)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:601)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:580)
    at Server.befTime(Server.java:261)
```

(the Line `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");` is Line Number 261 and returns the error...

Could someone please help me??

Add: The same -> SAME (copied & pasted) method works in another class WITHOUT any Errors...

Comment: The other class that this works in - is that on the same system, with the same default culture etc? Is the stack trace significantly longer than this? (Perhaps you've already got an enormous stack, and this just pushes it over the edge.)

Comment: Try to get the stack length using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length`. If it's very high you might want to print the stack and see why. Print it in `befTime()` method.

Comment: If you get a `StackOverflowError` the stack trace normally contains a lot of repeating blocks (could be several lines long). Please check for those as Jon Skeet suggested and if you get them post one or 2 of those blocks and if it's not too much the according code as well.

Comment: I got several Threads running in the Background, could that be the problem?

Comment: I am taking a guess here, but is it possible that your function Server.befTime() is called recursively, e.g., from within msgOut()?